# Include .NET framework in nLite iso

Tags: windows-xp, .net

How do I slipstream the .NET 2.0 (or .NET 3.5 for that matter) framework into an nLite Windows XP SP3 ISO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would start by reviewing the runonce explanation [Here](http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/view/web/31/).  After that, copy your .net binaries to the root of the cd before creating the ISO.  After that, add the runonce commands found [Here](http://www.msfn.org/board/lofiversion/index.php/t130466.html) to the runonce section under the unattended tab (ensuring that they are tailored for your setup, ie the paths are right in the commands).  That should work for you.  Good Luck.